# QGIS 2.10.1 - Categorized Style - Select and Deselct

Tags: qgis

I have a WFS layer that i have categorized in the style tab of the Layer properties.

This creates 50 or so categories that are now color coded which is exactly what i want.

How do i select 5 or 10 or all and toggle the visibility on and off ??

Comment: Do you want the toggle on/off to effect all the items selected with only one click?