# QGIS select items within style categorized

Tags: qgis, layers

I have the layer, where is a lot of styles categorized, as the layer is big.

[image]

Is there an opportunity to make the item selection just within the style categorized? Or should I make a selection based on these criteria and save it as a separate layer?

A similar issue I believe was raised here:

[QGIS 2.10.1 - Categorized Style - Select and Deselct](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186100/qgis-2-10-1-categorized-style-select-and-deselct)

but without an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: as of QGIS 3.26 (released 2022-06-17) it is now possible to [select by symbol category](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog326/index.html#feature-select-features-from-expression-based-symbols).

---

As far as I know there is no easy way to select only the items that fit within a certain style category. Here are a couple of options.

1. You could copy the relevant style rule (e.g. `"name" = 'JOINTING CHAMBER'`) for that category into Select by Expression and use that to select appropriately.
2. You can hide all categories in that layer (right click on any one of the categories and click Hide All Items), then only show the relevant category, and use the selection tool to drag across your relevant area. Using the selection tool manually will only select visible items so in this instance it will only select items in the relevant category. Not a good idea if you have a very large working area/extent as there's a higher likelihood of missing data.
3. If that category is something you want to interact with separately on a regular basis, while keeping it part of the larger dataset, you could duplicate the layer in QGIS (this does not create a copy of the base file but just duplicates the reference to it) - right click on layer and click Duplicate - then filter that duplicated layer to the relevant category (e.g. `"name" = 'JOINTING CHAMBER'`). Now whatever you do in that filtered layer - selection, moving, mass attribute update etc - will only affect the relevant features.

Comment: If I use "Select by expression" then all my style rules will be selected regardless of the area I would like to cover. I used to select these ones by polygon by far and I got everything from the selected layer instead of the one role only.